# Issue with Oracle sql AND OR operation precedence

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to write a query where I am performing a simple SELECT query in my procedure using AND and OR operations.. below is  the query..

problem is in my last AND block, its not returning the result as expected. Seems like AND and OR combinations are not working in expected precedence .

---

```
FROM  TABLE_A
  WHERE project = p_project
  AND version = p_version
  AND logical_name= p_logical_name
  AND ((operation_name= p_operation_name) OR (((p_operation_name IS NULL OR  p_operation_name <> operation_name) AND default_operation = 'Y')));
```

here if I get a p_name from my procedure call, WHERE portion should consider like

```
WHERE project = p_project
  AND version = p_version
   AND logical_name= p_logical_name
  AND ((operation_name= p_operation_name)
```

but if p_name does not match with name then in that case it should go to the next block where it check if p_name is null or p_name not available in DB and should check for default_operation = 'Y'

```
WHERE project = p_project
  AND version = p_version
  AND logical_name= p_logical_name
  AND (((p_operation_name IS NULL OR  p_operation_name <> operation_name) AND default_operation = 'Y')))
```

but its not working as expected.. its going on both block and returning me multiple results.

Comment: Shouldn't the last line start with an `OR`?

Comment: @shree.pat18 - not sure why you seeing this starting with OR.   ------AND ((name = p_name) OR (((p_name IS NULL OR  p_name <> name) AND default_operation = 'Y')));

Comment: `AND name = p_name
  AND (((p_name IS NULL OR  p_name <> name) AND default_operation = 'Y')))` - do you see that as well in your question?

Comment: I have first AND block, if that works then we are good else I have OR block which will further do some manipulations.. a OR comparison and then a AND

Comment: Please could you provide some sample data and required output, it will help to figure out the correct statement

Answer (score 0):

it does not make sense to add AND into OR brackets. You'd better extract it and make it simple (KISS ;-)

on the other hand you have concurrently excluding clauses

```
name = p_name OR p_name <> name
```

you should choose which one you need, cannot use both.

something like

```
FROM  TABLE_A
  WHERE project = p_project
  AND version = p_version
  AND name = p_name
  AND default_operation = 'Y'
  AND (name = p_name OR p_name IS NULL /*OR  p_name <> name*/);
```

Comment: thanks.. seems there was not naming confusion on my query. I have modified it. Could you please check and help me.

Comment: you've changed names but are again duplicated - operation_name= p_operation_name -> p_operation_name <> operation_name. I still think the above where clause is good

Answer (score 0):

indentation is required to make sense of these I always feel

```
SELECT
      *
FROM TABLE_A
WHERE project = p_project
      AND version = p_version
      AND (
            name = p_name
            OR (
                 (p_name IS NULL OR p_name <> name)
                AND
                 default_operation = 'Y'
               )
          )
```

Comment: thanks.. seems there was not naming confusion on my query. I have modified it. Could you please check and help me.

Comment: what did you change, just make the same change(s) in this

Comment: there are couple of column name like --name = p_name ... which was making no scense  to have. After that change, might be your query will change.

Comment: of course, if the column names change, or if the required logic changes, then this answer would change. I cannot however read minds no matter how hard I try :) Can you be specific about the changes?

Comment: ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows - same issue.   - getting multiple rows from your query.. ideally we should get one row.

Comment: That is an error from a scalar subquery that returns more than one row - there is no scalar subquery in what I proposed - so you are not testing fairly. There is no scalar subquery in the question either. Afraid I cannot help if you are testing "unknown things". Please don't keep adding comments here, you need to update your question.

Answer (score 0):

In your last where statement, try `NVL` for your `P_NAME`

EX:

```
WHERE project = p_project
  AND version = p_version
  AND name = NVL(p_name, NAME)
  AND (((p_name IS NULL OR  p_name <> name) AND default_operation = 'Y')))
```

This is because comparing `null` with equal will always fail, so if your `P_NAME` parameter is null, the equal statement will return `false`

Answer (score 0):

I think the below will work for you

```
WHERE project = p_project
  AND version = p_version
  AND
     (
        logical_name= p_logical_name
        OR
          (
            (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLE_A WHERE logical_name = p_logical_name) = 0 
            AND ((p_operation_name IS NULL OR  p_operation_name <> operation_name) 
            AND default_operation = 'Y')
          )
     )
```

What it does, it gets `logical_name= p_logical_name` and if that fails it gets records where the predicates match another block.

Comment: ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows - same issue.